# PHP how to forward a form through a controller and then back to another page

Tags: php, curl

I have a standard webform that calls a php controller block. I want to add in a few extra fields and forward the page to another php page. I have it working using GET but don't really want the information on the top browser window as it looks messy. I would like to use POST. The only half solution i have seen so far is using CURL. This dosn't work?

This is an example:

```
$fields= array( 'datapack' => rawurlencode($forward)  );

$curl = curl_init('knowledge_wizard.php');
curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $fields);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I have googled it a number of times and the answers are random and some involve javascript. I don't want that as it all should be hidden from the client.

Thanks in advance :)